# Can not change innerHTML with javascript of p element by .getElementById method

Tags: javascript, html

Here is the HTML code ==>
'''

```
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Counter</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./main.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="./main.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="head">
            <h1>Counter</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="number">
            <h1 id='num'></h1>
        </div>
        <div class="buttons">
            <button class="btn" name="lower-count" id="btn-1" onclick="lowerCount()">Lower Count</button>
            <button class="btn" name="add-count" id="btn-2" onclick="addCount()">Add Count</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

'''

---

and here is my Javascript ==>
'''

```
var currentNum= document.getElementById('num').innerhtml = 0;
```

'''

Answer (score 1):

The HTML part of `.innerHTML()` should be all caps.

Answer (score 1):

Javascript functions are case sensitive - it should be written as follows. Note the upper-case **HTML** part :

```
document.getElementById('num').innerHTML = 0;
```

also note that you were doing two assignations, not sure whether that was accidental. I removed the

```
var currentNum =
```

from the beginning.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value. [How to Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Kind Regards.

Answer (score 0):

```js
document.getElementById('num').innerHTML=3;
```

```html
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Counter</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./main.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="./main.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="head">
            <h1>Counter</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="number">
            <h1 id='num'></h1>
        </div>
        <div class="buttons">
            <button class="btn" name="lower-count" id="btn-1" onclick="lowerCount()">Lower Count</button>
            <button class="btn" name="add-count" id="btn-2" onclick="addCount()">Add Count</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

It should be `document.getElementById('num').innerHTML = 0;`

```js
document.getElementById('num').innerHTML = 0;
    
    function addCount(){
     document.getElementById('num').innerHTML= (+document.getElementById('num').innerHTML) + 1
    }
    
        function lowerCount(){
     document.getElementById('num').innerHTML= (+document.getElementById('num').innerHTML) - 1
    }
```

```html
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Counter</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./main.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="./main.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="head">
            <h1>Counter</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="number">
            <h1 id='num' value=''></h1>
        </div>
        <div class="buttons">
            <button class="btn" name="lower-count" id="btn-1" onclick="lowerCount()">Lower Count</button>
            <button class="btn" name="add-count" id="btn-2" onclick="addCount()">Add Count</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of this:

```
var currentNum= document.getElementById('num').innerhtml = 0;
```

You need to type this:

```
var currentNum= document.getElementById('num').innerHTML = 0;
```

You need to capitalize the html part of innerHTML

Comment: Sorry, I just pasted the wrong code of javascript I did write innerHTML but it didn't work as well.

Comment: Then make sure you have an element with the id of 'num'. Also, see that it is the only element in your html code with the id 'num'. Because the id attribute should always be unique.